# Selecting author name field from Atom feed using LINQ (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, atom-feed

I'm trying to select the "name" field from the author node in an ATOM feed using LINQ. I can get all the fields I need like so:

```
XDocument stories = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
var story = from entry in stories.Descendants(xmlns + "entry")
            select new Story
            {
                Title = entry.Element(xmlns + "title").Value,
                Content = entry.Element(xmlns + "content").Value
            };
```

How would I go about selecting the author -> name field in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically want:

```
entry.Element(xmlns + "author").Element(xmlns + "name").Value
```

But you might want to wrap that in an extra method so you can easily take appropriate action if either the author or name elements are missing. You might also want to think about what you want to happen if there's more than one author.

The feed might also have an author element... just another thing to bear in mind.

Answer (score 3):

It could be something like this:

```
        var story = from entry in stories.Descendants(xmlns + "entry")
                    from a in entry.Descendants(xmlns + "author")
                    select new Story
                    {
                        Title = entry.Element(xmlns + "title").Value,
                        Content = entry.Element(xmlns + "subtitle").Value,
                        Author = new AuthorInfo(
                            a.Element(xmlns + "name").Value,
                            a.Element(xmlns + "email").Value,
                            a.Element(xmlns + "uri").Value
                         )
                    };
```

Comment: I was thinking about using some kind of nested LINQ but wasn't sure how to do it. I'll have a play with your suggestion, cheers!